# Experimenting with node-webkit: node-odbc fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-webkit, node-odbc

I am trying to create a desktop application using [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js). The app queries an Oracle database. To make the connection to the database, I use [node-odbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc).

I did a preliminary test with node.js to make sure that I can actually query the database using my installed Oracle drivers. Here's what I did:

**`index.js:`**

```js
var db = require('odbc')();
var cn = 'DSN=****;Uid=****;Pwd=****;';

db.open(cn, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  db.query('select 42 from dual', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(data);

    db.close(function () {
      console.log('done');
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this, I get the following output, as expected:

```
> node index.js
[ { '42': 42 } ]
done
```

Then I created the following node-webkit package:

**`index.html:`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var db = require('odbc')();
    var cn = 'DSN=****;Uid=****;Pwd=****;';

    function queryDb() {
        db.open(cn, function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);

          db.query('select 42 from dual', function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            console.log(data);

            db.close(function () {
              console.log('done');
            });
          });
        });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="queryDb()" value="Query" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**`package.json:`**

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo-odbc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies":
  {
    "odbc": "*"
  }
}
```

But when I run this in node-webkit and open the console, following error is displayed:

```
C:\path\to\package\node_modules\odbc\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:79 
    Uncaught Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
C:\path\to\package\node_modules\odbc\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node
```

- I am using nw.js v0.12.2.

Comment: Is this on the same machine you were testing with when it worked?  Just based on the error, it looks like a 64 bit vs 32 bit issue.

Comment: Same machine. Directories side by side. My node.js, node-webkit installations are x86. Oracle client is 32 bit. My machine is 64 bit though.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the ODBC drivers are 32bit.

Therefore follow these steps:

1. Compile node-odbc binary modules as 32 bit

   ```
   node-gyp clean configure build --arch=ia32 --msvs_version=2015
   ```
2. Use a 32-bit executable of Node.js to run the application